# Using only variables, how to append a child to the parent?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two variables. One for the video element and the other for the source.

```
var videoHTML = this.elem.innerHTML;
//Output: <video data-echo="path/video.mp4"></video>

var sourceVideo = "<source" + " " + "src=\"path/video.mp4\"" "type=\"video/mp4\"" />";
//Output: <source src="path/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```

I'm attempting to create a third variable that combines both of them. Something such as...

```
var videoHybrid = videoHTML + sourceVideo;

// Output: <video data-echo="path/video.mp4"></video>
//         <source src="path/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```

How would I go about creating a variable the will produce the following result?

```
<video data-echo="path/video.mp4">
    <source src="path/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: What is `videoHTML`? Does that contain `<video.../>`?

Comment: @putvande See the comment below the assignment

Comment: Is there a reason you have to do this with strings, rather than DOM manipulation functions?

Comment: Yes, I will be lazy loading video. For it to work in IE8/IE9 I need to delete the video node and then add it back.

Comment: Why can't you do that with DOM methods?

Comment: Okay, let me take a step back. I'm expanding upon [Suave.js](http://toddmotto.com/hacking-the-html5-video-element-with-suave-js/). This is the first step before I get into lazy loading video. Todd is using variables to create the source tags before inserting them into the DOM. Since this is my first foray into JavaScript I wanted to follow his lead. I'm almost finished [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/n7AfQ/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it as long as `videoHTML` just has one pair of matching elements, as in your example:

```
videoHybrid = videoHTML.replace(/></, '>' + sourceVideo + '<');
```

If it's more complicated, it would be better to use DOM manipulation methods like `appendChild()`.

Comment: It worked! You're correct about it being complicated—now that I have it functional I quickly found out it doesn't work in IE or Firefox. Plus, when adding additional attributes to the HTML {mp4, ogv, webm} it breaks. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/CzY4R/) Anyways, thanks again for the help!

Comment: I think your title could use improving. When you say "using only variables", I think you mean "using only strings". DOM objects would be in variables, too.

Answer (score 1):

To get that, you can simply get the src which you are having as sourceVideo and append it to the main videoHTML code.

I would like to ask you to use jQuery, and do this:

```
videoHTML.find('video').append(sourceVideo);
```

Why I did this, is because you're having an HTML content as the variable, and jQuery would find that for you. And then append the variable (which in turn is a HTML string too) to that first variable.

This way, the HTML of yours

```
<video data-echo="path/video.mp4">
   // nothing..
</video>
```

Will get this one

```
<source src="path/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
```

As its child element!